# Using Python, recursively create symbolic links for all .jpg files created within the last 24 hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, operating-system

I store my photo library organized by year and event, for example:

```
/mnt/mediapool/images1/2020/Day at the beach/IMG1.JPG
/mnt/mediapool/images1/2020/Day at the beach/IMG2.JPG
/mnt/mediapool/images1/2021/Sunset/IMG15.JPG
```

Using Python3, how can I recurse through all my images and create symbolic links inside another directory that list all images created within the last 24 hours (and 7-days, 30-days, etc..)?

For example:

```
/mnt/mediapool/sorted/last-24h/IMG1.JPG (symbolic link to /mnt/mediapool/images1/2020...)
/mnt/mediapool/sorted/last-24h/IMG2.JPG (symbolic link to /mnt/mediapool/images1/2020...)
/mnt/mediapool/sorted/last-24h/IMG3.JPG (symbolic link to /mnt/mediapool/images1/2020...)
/mnt/mediapool/sorted/last-7d/IMG1.JPG (symbolic link to /mnt/mediapool/images1/2020...)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`os.walk(/mnt/mediapool/images1/)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to recurse through that directory tree.

   - remember to use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create a full path from the parent dir to the file
2. For each file, check the creation time or the modified time with [`os.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat)

   - compare with the current time in seconds and calculate 24hrs/7days/30days
   - since you've got last 7 days including everything in the last 24 hours, use a loop to check each time-window and execute the next steps conditionally
3. Create the necessary directory tree for where the link would go, using [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

   - doesn't throw errors for existing dirs and allows creating a tree structure
4. Create the link to the target image with [`os.symlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.symlink) or [`pathlib.Path.symlink_to()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.symlink_to)

   - (you may be able to skip step 3 when doing step 4)